# Dynamically create template slots in Bootstrap Vue <b-table>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vue-slot

I'm trying to add HTML to headers in a Vue table.  Knowing the key of the field I can do something like this:

```
<template v-slot:head(my_key)="data">
<span v-html="data.field.label" />
</template>
```

However, my table will have an unknown number of columns each with unknown keys to start (pulled in through axios).  Is there a way to dynamically set `my_key` after I retrieve all of the keys from my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dynamic slot names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names) to target the header slot with a variable.  Assuming `my_key` in your pseudo-code example above is the name of a variable, then your example could be rewritten with a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```html
<template v-slot:[`head(${my_key})`]="data">
```

You can then use the table's `fields` array, or any array of keys, with a `v-for` to target all of the table header slots:

```html
<template v-for="field in fields" v-slot:[`head(${field})`]="data">
  <span v-html="data.field.label" />
</template>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  fields: ['a', 'b', 'c']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completion and for people that might be looking at older code (and perhaps struggling with the syntax as I was), an alternative solution to @Dan's one, based on a [depreciated syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute) could be something like:

```html
<template
  v-for="{key} in fields"
  :slot="`HEAD_${key}`"
  slot-scope="{label}"  
>
  <span v-html="label" />
</template>
```